# get top offset of a div on window scroll

Tags: javascript, offset

I'm trying to get the top offset of an element using this code but it's not working it's getting the same position every time which is 108 and not changing though the margin-top is 100px only

http://jsfiddle.net/np16jm3o/1/

```
$(function() {
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            var container= $("#container");
            console.log(container.offset().top);
        });
    });
```

HTML code:

```
<div id="container" style="float: left; width: 100%; background: #ccc; height: 1200px; margin-top: 100px;">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The offset function returns the position relative to the document, so this is not only the offset of the element itself, but also its parent(s).
When you look at your example in your fiddle, you can see that the body also has a margin of 8 px, thus resulting in the 108px you already saw.

If you really want to get the offset relative to its parent, you could substract the offset of the parent. You could also use the .scrollTop function to get the height you already scrolled if you want to get the position relative to the page.

Comment: Thanks for explanation but how to get the offset according to the page not the document so it gets changed